# Eclipse How to Disable Autocomplete For =

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, formatting

I am using eclipse mars. I have turned on on autocomplete in content assist for Java with

```
.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@
```

for the activation triggers.

This has created a situation where the = character is now automatically filling in text when I don't want it to. I will type the left hand side:

```
public void method(String param1, String param2) {
    String someString
}
```

then type = and this becomes:

```
public void method(String param1, String param2) {
    String someString param1=
}
```

It seems like it is autofilling with the first parameter from the method.

Is there some way to keep autofill without having = triggering autocomplete?

Comment: Are you sure you have not added the '=' character by accident to the list of auto activation trigger characters for Java? I tried to reproduce your issue but it worked as expected.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce and I can't. Note that if I try it does not automatically do it but if I Ctrl-Space it I get param1 as the first choice. However even if I do that I get `String someString=param1` not the `param1` first and the `=` after.

Comment: Yeah, = is not a part of the activation triggers. If by default it doesn't have that problem I might do some comparing with a clean copy of eclipse

Comment: Wow, apparently restarting eclipse fixed the problem. I have no idea what was going on. Thanks for looking into this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out restarting eclipse fixed this problem.